# CodeIgniter URL rewriting not work

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm locked with my system...
I changed the settings in my config.php file to have URLs with parameters.
Suddenly I have a product controller that displays the id that I pass URL parameter.

http://localhost:8888/mywebsite/index.php?c=product&m=index&id_product=12

This URL works now I want to get a url of the type:

http://localhost:8888/mywebsite/product/my-product-12

So I put this in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?c=product&m=index&id_product=$2 [L]
```

But the page displays : The requested URL `/index.php/product/my-product-12.html` was **not found** on this server.

My htaccess file :

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1         [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?c=product&m=index&id_product=$2 [L]
```

My config.php file :

```html
<?php

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/mywebsite/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd'; 
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your new RewriteRule after RewriteBase:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?c=product&m=index&id_product=$2 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1         [L,QSA]
```

Because you have to rewrite first to `index.php?c=product`

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
I do that and i've this error message in my page :

Not Found

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Try now without `.html`. That was in your code but not in your exemple url.

Comment: Same result... I don't understand :(